# How to get post thumbnail to be equal to set media size

Tags: post-thumbnails, media

I'm new to learning WP theme development so I may not have worded the title perfectly but that's the best way I could think to explain it.

My theme is on a localhost so I can't link to it but here is a screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjJ2j.png

What I want is for the_post_thumbnail to always fill the specified thumbnail media settings.

Currently the thumbnails will be different sizes depending on the width / height ratio.

I have gone into WP Dashboard and set the media thumbnail size for medium at 250px wide by 150px tall.  I want the image to always fill that space, don't care if it's cut off but I want it to be that size.

Thanks, I hope I explained it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[the_post_thumbnail](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail) allows for size specificiations. So you would do:

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail('medium'); ?>
```

if you changed the image dimensions in the admin, you will need to go back and re-upload the images so they crop to the correct size that you set up

If the issue is the dimensions of the image you are probably looking for a hard-crop. The best bet is to set up a new image size with [add_image_size](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size) in your functions.php.

```
add_image_size( 'new-image-name', 250, 150, true );
```

then re-uploading images then

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail('new-image-name'); ?>
```

Comment: Just tried doing that however no change, also tried regenerating thumbnails with no change.  The featured image I set in the edit post page is what is used for the thumbnail in this case correct?  And yeah that is the code I am using to display the thumbnails.

Comment: check revised answer